# How to round to nearest fraction of another number?

Tags: c++, math, numbers

I want to add a special scaling mode where it snaps to the closest multiple.  Right now, scaling up is fine, it's linear and goes something like this:

```
 // f(x := 35, n := 32) = 32
 // f(x := 66, n := 32) = 64
 x = floor(x / n) * n
```

But for scaling down, I want some sort of inverse exponential:

```
 // f(x := 18, n := 32) = 16
 // f(x := 12, n := 32) = 8
 // f(x := 7, n := 32) = 4
```

An implementation suggestion without using a loop in any language would suffice.  My current implementation is as follows (which 100% works):

```
float ScaleMultiple(float value, float multiple) {
    if (value > multiple) {
        return(floor(value / multiple) * multiple);
    } else if (value < multiple) {
        do {
            multiple /= 2.0f;
        } while (value >= multiple);
        return(multiple);
    } else {
        return(value);
    }
}
```

`multiple` is a positive floating point number and not necessarily a multiple of 2 and is at least equal to 1.
`value` is a positive floating point number and is at least equal to 1.

Comment: Is n always a power of 2?

Comment: @user3344003 It is a floating-point number. Updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand the three examples you provided. Please explain them, or add a lot more.

Comment: Could one summarize the "inverse function" as: Given n and x (x<n), find the next smallest divisor m<=x of n? Or find the next smallest number m<=x, such that (x-m) and (n mod m) are both small, for some balance of "both small" still to be specified?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've put in my working code. Portion in middle of it is what I'd like to optimize if possible.

Comment: I don't believe this works. In the second case it can reduce 'multiple' to zero and then loop forever.

Comment: Okay, for the sake of argument, let's assumed that `value` will be a reasonable value above 1.

Answer (score 0):

32 / 18 ~= 1.8 ~= 2, the result you want is 32 / 2, right? For the case of 12 and 32, this would yield 3 though, not four. In order to get there, take the log-2 of that number, round that to an even number and then convert back. However, this has the problem that it doesn't work properly when `n` is not a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct results for the values you give in Java as follows:

```
int f = (int)Math.pow(2,(int)(Math.log(x)/Math.log(2)));
```

There's insufficient information provided to answer the question for arbitrary *n.*

Comment: A formula, of course, or a lot more examples. Note that this expression here is independent of *n.*